# Test Class for Contact Trigger is not working

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have this class below for the contact trigger. But, the Test class I wrote does not seem to work and I can't tell why it does not give any coverage.

Trigger

```
 trigger contactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {
   if(contHandlerClass.contactRecursion)
    return;
  //contHandlerClass.contactRecursion = true;
        contHandlerClass.getRecentTaskInformation(Trigger.new);

}
```

Class

```
public class contHandlerClass {
    public static boolean contactRecursion =false; // to avoid the "maximum trigger depth exceeded" error


    public static void getRecentTaskInformation(List<Contact> contacts) {

        System.debug('print the list' + contacts);
 //Tasks     
        List<Contact> contactsWithLastTasks = [
            SELECT Id, Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c,
               Name, (
                    SELECT Subject, ActivityDate, Owner.Name,Task.WhoId,
                        Type_of_Interaction__c
                    FROM Tasks
                    ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC 
                    LIMIT 1
                )
            FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contacts
        ];

        for (Contact c : contactsWithLastTasks) {
            if (!c.tasks.isEmpty()) {
                Task lastTask = c.tasks[0];
                System.debug('print Tasks' + lastTask);

                c.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c = lastTask.Subject;
               // c.Contact_Task_Date__c = lastTask.ActivityDate;
                // may be create field and set it text "Task" to identify if it is Task or Event

                System.debug('Print contacts list one by one?'+ contactsWithLastTasks);
                System.debug('Field one?'+ c.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c);
               // System.debug('Field two?'+ c.Contact_Task_Date__c);

            }
        }
        /*
        If(!contactsWithLastTasks.isEmpty()){
        Update contactsWithLastTasks;
        }*/
        contactHandlerClass.contactRecursion = true;
        update contactsWithLastTasks;
        contactHandlerClass.contactRecursion = false;
```

Test Class

```
@isTest 
public class contactHandlerClassTest {

    static testMethod void contactTastUpdate() {

  //Account
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name ='Test';
        insert acc;


  //Contact     
        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName ='Test';
        cont.LastName ='testContact';
        cont.Last_Activity_Subject__c='Run Test Trigger';
        cont.accountid =acc.id;
        cont.Last_Activity_Date__c = Date.parse('6/15/2019');
        cont.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c = 'Run Test Trigger';
        insert cont;

  //Task
        Task u = new Task();
        u.ownerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        u.whatid = acc.id;
        u.whoid = cont.id;
        u.Subject='Run Test Trigger';
        u.Status='Not Started';
        u.Priority='Normal';
        u.ActivityDate = Date.parse('6/16/2019');



        Test.startTest();
        insert u;
       // insert someEvent;
        update cont;       
        Test.stopTest();


        cont =[ SELECT Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c From Contact WHERE Id =: cont.id ];
        System.assertEquals('Run Test Trigger', cont.Most_Recent_Contact_Task_Subject__c);

    }

}
```

I am at 77% coverage now. Why these lines do not get covered?

[image]

Comment: There's a crucial link missing here: the trigger that calls this class. This test class also fails one of the key expectations of a test class: it does not verify behavior through assert statements.

Comment: I have updated the Trigger and also included the assert statement. I wonder that's what you were asking?

Comment: On my reading, at least, you should get a small but nonzero amount of coverage from this test. Can you confirm whether you get exactly zero coverage? Do the debug lines in your class print?

Comment: Thanks David. I am at 77% coverage and trying to hit closer to 100%. I posted a screenshot where it did not cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here is your recursion guard, which is using an overly-simplistic model and inhibiting the second run of your trigger.

Your trigger runs once at

```
    insert cont;
```

and sets `contactRecursion` to `true`. It retains that value for the remainder of the transaction - the entirety of the unit test run. Your trigger is invoked a second time at

```
    update cont;
```

at which point it immediately returns. Hence, your code never runs in a context with a Task available, so it does not cover that code path.

The fix: use a safer recursion guard that only inhibits explicit recursion. Remove the recursion guard assignment

```
contactHandlerClass.contactRecursion = true;
```

from the trigger body. Instead, in your handler class, change

```
    If(!contactsWithLastTasks.isEmpty()){
    Update contactsWithLastTasks;
    }
```

to

```
contactHandlerClass.contactRecursion = true;
update contactsWithLastTasks
contactHandlerClass.contactRecursion = false;
```

Then you'll only block trigger runs that are actually invoked recursively by your code.